# Graph theory Orientable Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I need help doing this question, and I believe a 'standard' solution would require proof by induction. Here is the question: Suppose that n ≥ 3 and a simple graph G has n vertices and at least $\frac{n^2−3n+6}{2}$ edges. Prove that G is orientable.

Comment: What does "orientable" mean?

Comment: the following are equivalent; a graph is orientable, all edges of the graph belong to a cycle, there are no bridges on the graph.

Comment: OK, you want to figure out what's the MOST edges a graph on $n$ vertices WITH a bridge can have, and add $1$; an $n$-vertex graph with that many edges can't have a bridge, so it's orientable. If you've previously had a problem about the most edges an $n$-vertex graph can have and be DISCONNECTED, this is similar, but you will have one more edge (the bridge). Another hint: $\frac{n^2-3n+6}2=\binom{ n-1}2+1.$